# Android Webview not reading CSS from my web server

Tags: android, webview

okay, here's the thing. I am currently working on android app which loads the url from my web server. the server contains the HTML and CSS im working on. when i run the app, the webview is not reading the css which is working properly when i load it in my web browser in pc.

Here is when i run the app/when i load it in mobile's browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXUnz.png

Here is when i load it in my pc's browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XATtJ.png

Comment: Is the page getting displayed?

Comment: Yes but it doesnt read my css. ill post screenshot

Comment: Here is when i load it in my pc's browser: http://imgur.com/4Ev8WKc,t4YY6GA#0

Comment: Here is when i run the app/when i load it in mobile's browser: http://imgur.com/4Ev8WKc,t4YY6GA#1

Comment: which mobile os version are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some solutions for the issue. Try these, don't know if they will solve as you haven't provided any code or url link with question.

Did you enable javascript in webview ? If not then enable using the code below :

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

There is a known bug in the file protocol for a few android versions. If you are referencing files with url parameters a HTTP 404 (file not found) occurs and the file is not loaded.

In your case the the styles.css might not be getting loaded.

Get help here :

https://coderwall.com/p/xnbawa

http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/fixing-the-broken-honeycomb-and-ics-webview/